# How can I render this Json objects in vue.js?

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js

JSON String from external API

> occupations : { "1": { "name": "Maler / Lackierer", "skills": { "606":
> { "id": 606, "name": "Qualifikation:", "type": "slider_data", "value":
> "Meister" }, "616": { "id": 616, "name": "Arbeitserfahrung in Jahren",
> "type": "slider_range", "unit": "Jahre", "value": 2 } } } } - 1

```
data() {
    return {
      myObj: {},
   
    }
  },

mounted() {
    axios.get('https://xy',{
      dataType: 'json',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',  
      },
    })
      .then(res => {
        //JSON.parse(res)
        this.applicantdata = JSON.parse(res.data.applicantdata)
        console.log(JSON.parse(res.data.applicantdata))
        this.myObj = this.applicantdata
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        // Manage errors if found any
      })
  },
```

My try:

```
<div v-for="(name, propertyName, index) in myObj.formatted" :key="name.id">
        {{ propertyName }} : {{ name }} - {{ index }}
      </div>
```

One level deeper:

```
  <div v-for="(name, propertyName, index) in myObj.formatted.occupations[1]" :key="name.id">
        {{ propertyName }} : {{ name }} - {{ index }}
      </div>
```

My problem is the index [1] -> [606] / [616] i don't know this id in another results ?!

Answer (score 0):

```
That's it 

  <div v-for="(row, id) in myObj.formatted.occupations" :key="id">
        <div v-for="(name, propertyName, index) in row" :key="name.id">
          {{ propertyName }} : {{ name }} - {{ index }}
           <p v-for="skill in name" :key="skill.id">
            {{ skill.name }} {{ skill.value }}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```